# JS will not loop, stops after first loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written the code below to act as a simple slideshow in the header of a clients website. Now, the only problem is when I put it into a for or a while loop it gets to the end of the first loop and then stops.

I've tried using calling togglinga() in the last callback, I've tried, wrapping the whole thing in a for and while loop, I've tried creating a different function that calls this one and then using that same function name in the final call back but get the same result everytime. I'd really appreciate someone casting their eye over this to see if they can see anything I can't....

```
    function triggerAnimation(){
        $("#logoareacontainer").delay(15000).fadeOut(3000, function() {
            $("#title-1").fadeIn(0).delay(0, function() {
                $("#cdsl-1-1").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(0, function(){
                    $("#cdsl-1-2").fadeIn(0).delay(2000).fadeOut(0, function(){
                      $("#logoareacontainer").fadeIn(1000).css({display:'block'})
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: use https://github.com/caolan/async . look at 'parallel' and 'series' functions

Comment: **1.** You are using jQuery, not plain vanilla JavaScript. **2.** There are no loops anywhere in your posted code. **3.** The look of this code, while esthetically pleasing, should trigger a feeling of _There has got to be a more sensible way to achieve this_. I would Google `jQuery slideshow plug-in` for starters ;)

Comment: You should consider rewriting this code to have a configurations array of objects that details what elelemnts to fadein/fadeout and with what delay, and then do a recursive setTimeout function instead it would make your life much easier

Comment: @Pinocchio take some element, fade it in, then wait, then back, then move on to the next element. Looping over some table would make much sense here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much shorter and easier if you break this into functions that can be called in a cyclical manner.

Note that `.delay()` doesn't accept a callback function, which was a big part of the problem.

***Here's a demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/kjaHZ/

```
// for each "title-", keep track of how many "cdsl-"s there are
var titles = [null, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1];

start();

// start it off
function start() {
    $("#logoareacontainer").delay(1500).fadeOut(3000, function () {
        doTitle(1);
    });
}
```

---

```
// this starts a "title-" section
function doTitle(i) {
    if (i < titles.length) {
        // do the "title-" for the given "i" variable
        $("#title-" + i).fadeIn(0, function () {
            // after fading in, do the "cdsl-" ids
            doCDSL(i, 1);
        });
    } else {
        // or if "i" is >= titles.length, we're done
        $("#logoareacontainer").fadeIn(1000).css({display:'block'});
    }
}
```

---

```
// this starts a "cdsl-" section
function doCDSL(i, j) {
    $("#cdsl-" + i + "-" + j).fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(2000)
    .fadeOut(0, function () {
        if (j < titles[i]) {
            // move to the next "cdsl-"
            doCDSL(i, j+1);
        } else {
            // or do the next "title-"
            $("#title-" + i).fadeOut(1000).css({display:'none'})
            doTitle(i+1);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

although your code is pretty awfull here u are :) u missed `()`

```
function togglinga(){ triggerAnimation(); };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the code in a loop, because it is asynchronous. The loop would just start all the animations at once, because the outermost call won't wait until all the animations are complete.

At the innermost level, just call `triggerAnimation` to make it restart.